# How to smooth the movement of my player in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, movement

I would like to move my player from one position to another position using key detection. I would like to know how I can make the player movement smooth.

Code:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        xSpeed = -1f;
        ySpeed = 0f;
        X = X + xSpeed;
        Y = Y + ySpeed;
        Vector3 NewPos = new Vector3(X, Y, 0);
        gameObject.transform.position = NewPos;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        xSpeed = 1f;
        ySpeed = 0f;
        X = X + xSpeed;
        Y = Y + ySpeed;
        Vector3 NewPos = new Vector3(X, Y, 0);
        gameObject.transform.position = NewPos;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        xSpeed = 0f;
        ySpeed = 1f;
        X = X + xSpeed;
        Y = Y + ySpeed;
        Vector3 NewPos = new Vector3(X, Y, 0);
        gameObject.transform.position = NewPos;
    }

    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        xSpeed = 0f;
        ySpeed = -1f;
        X = X + xSpeed;
        Y = Y + ySpeed;
        Vector3 NewPos = new Vector3(X, Y, 0);
        gameObject.transform.position = NewPos;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: -1 for lack of research. Unitys own website has a plethora of tutorials; several of which answer this question. We expect *some degree* of research effort, on your behalf, before posting a question to GameDev.SE.

Answer (score -1):

The most basic approach is, as stated in the link in the comments, to multiply your movement with `Time.deltaTime` in the Update-method of your gameobject.

`Time.deltaTime` is the time passed between the last frame (update) and the current.

In your case:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
{
    xSpeed = -1f;
    ySpeed = 0f;
    //Consider to increase your speed or add a new factor to multiply with, otherwise your movement will slow down significantly 
    X = X + xSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    Y = Y + ySpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 NewPos = new Vector3(X, Y, 0);
    gameObject.transform.position = NewPos;
}
```

Comment: It is not working it doesn't move 1x or 1y like if it is at 0,0 and i click A it goes to 0.4830474 instead of 1,0

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, that you have to increase your speed or mulitipy an additional factor. Of course the multiplying only the deltaTime will slow it down heavily

Comment: The comment you point to is actually notification that the question is marked for closure. If you agree with it, you should not copy an answer across. You should not be answering, at all.

Comment: Thanks for this advise. But what is the reason behind not answering at all? I didn't know such a rule.
I didn't just copy the answer from the link, I tried to include the problem. In my opinion its a bit rude, to prevent other to answer this question even though it's a duplicate or whatever, especially down voting my answer, which is technically correct!

Comment: In my opinion it's not fair and a bit toxic to down-vote my answer, because I never heared about this rule and saw questions marked as duplicate were answered. Just tell me, that it is not common or not wanted to do that. Its not about losing some of the rep, but its about the behavior, which up sets me!